# how to reuse two (or more) sequences of chained transitions in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I have to apply two very long sequences of chained transitions, which differ mainly on the order of transitions, and I'm looking for a compact way to code.

As a toy example, consider the case where the sequence orders should be `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`g`,`h` and `e`,`f`,`g`,`h`,`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`. I've tried with the code below, but it doesn't work. Notice that the transitions could have different properties (`delay`, `duration`, `ease`, and so on) and they could apply to different attributes (`x`, `y`, `width`, `height` or `cx`, `cy`, `r`, and so on) and styles. For example, transition `a` could refer to `width`, transition `b` to `height`, transition `c` to `x`, transition `d` to `y`, transition `e` to `transform` attribute, transition `f` to `color` style, etcetera.

P.S.: This question has the same aim of my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459212/a-compact-way-to-code-chained-transitions-in-d3) one but there I used a too much simple coding case that misguided answers.

Is there any way to code this in a compact way?

```
var t1 = d3
.transition() // transition "a" specifications 
...
.transition() // transition "b" specifications 
...
.transition() // transition "c" specifications 
...
.transition() // transition "d" specifications 
...
;
var t2 = d3
.transition() // transition "e" specifications 
...
.transition() // transition "f" specifications 
...
.transition() // transition "g" specifications 
...
.transition() // transition "h" specifications 
...
;
someelement1
.transition(t1).transition(t2); 
someelement2
.transition(t2).transition(t1);
```

Comment: Your previous question was very similar; can you apply the insights gained from the answers to that question to this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a compact way to code chained transitions in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459212/a-compact-way-to-code-chained-transitions-in-d3)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I rewrote my question since SO Meta suggests to do so: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374411/what-to-do-for-a-poorly-explained-question. In my previous question I've used a too much simple example which has been misinterpreted but my problem is much broader. All transitions don't refer only to color as I have clearly stated here.

Comment: You can apply the same principles as were suggested in your previous question -- e.g. my answer to this Q would basically be the same as to the previous one: create a function or functions to apply a set of transitions to a selection. If your previous question was misinterpreted, you might consider whether the problem statement was clear enough.

Comment: btw, the `t1` argument to `d3.transition(t1)` is [the name for a transition](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#selecting-elements), to enable sets of transitions to be synchronised and allow reuse of properties of the transition, e.g. duration, delay, etc. It can't be used to apply a whole set of transformations to a selection as you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, my code is wrong. I asked exactly for this.

Comment: You can use the answers to your previous question to correct your code here. As I said before, the principles for solving this problem are exactly the same as those used in the previous question: use functions to apply a saved set of transformations.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the method is easily replicable if transitions refer to the *same* attribute. Otherwise, it becomes very intricate. In other words, I'm looking for a different solution: can (transition) functions be chained by a sequenced code (and not loop or something similar), and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the principles for answering this question are the same as your previous question. In this case, you have a set of different transitions that might be applied in any order referred to by different keys. Let's store them in an object:

```
var transitions = {
  a: function(sel){ return sel.transition().duration(1000).delay(1000).attr('cy', 200) },
  b: function(sel){ return sel.transition().duration(2000).delay(0).attr('r', 40) },
  c: function(sel){ return sel.transition().duration(500).delay(1500).attr('fill', 'red') },
  d: function(sel){ return sel.transition().duration(1500).delay(500).attr('opacity', 0.5) },
  e: function(sel){ return sel.transition().duration(1000).delay(3000).attr('cy', 300) },
  f: function(sel){ return sel.transition().duration(2000).delay(0).attr('r', 60) },
  g: function(sel){ return sel.transition().duration(500).delay(1500).attr('fill', 'magenta') },
  h: function(sel){ return sel.transition().duration(1500).delay(500).attr('opacity', 0.25) }
};
```

Each function takes a `d3.selection` object and applies specific transition parameters and sets of transformations to it. These functions can be as long and complicated as you like. I am lazy with little imagination so they only do one transformation in this version.

There's already a bit of code repetition here, so let's take out the conversion of the selection to a transition, and use `this` instead of passing an argument:

```
var transitions = {
  a: function(){ return this.duration(1000).delay(1000).attr('cy', 200) },
  b: function(){ return this.duration(2000).delay(0).attr('r', 40) },
  c: function(){ return this.duration(500).delay(1500).attr('fill', 'red') },
  d: function(){ return this.duration(1500).delay(500).attr('opacity', 0.5) },
  e: function(){ return this.duration(1000).delay(3000).attr('cy', 300) },
  f: function(){ return this.duration(2000).delay(0).attr('r', 60) },
  g: function(){ return this.duration(500).delay(1500).attr('fill', 'magenta') },
  h: function(){ return this.duration(1500).delay(500).attr('opacity', 0.25) }
};
```

Now we can perform these transitions by calling code like

```
transitions['a'].call( selection.transition() )
transitions.f.call( d3.select('circle').transition() )
```

You want to specify an array of transitions to apply to a selection, something like this:

```
apply_transitions( group.select(":nth-child(1)"), ['a','b','c','d'] );
apply_transitions( group.select(":nth-child(2)"), ['e','f','g','h'] );
```

This could be implemented as follows:

```
/**
* apply a series of transitions to a selection
*
* @param selection - d3 selection
* @param tr_arr - array of transition identifiers, referring to functions in the `transitions` object
*/
function apply_transitions( selection, tr_arr ) {

  // turn the current selection into a d3.transition
  // call the transition function referred to by the first ID in the array
  // with the d3.transition as the `this` context
  // note that the function returns a transition object, so it can be chained
  transitions[ tr_arr[0] ].call( selection.transition() )
  // add a handler to be applied at the end of the transition
    .on('end', function(){
      // if there are more transitions to be applied, call
      // apply_transitions again with tr_arr minus the first element
      // note that the `this` context in the `on` function is a DOM element,
      // so use `d3.select(this)` to turn it into a d3 selection
      if ( tr_arr.length > 1 ) {
        apply_transitions( d3.select(this), tr_arr.slice(1) );
      }
    })
}
```

Live action example:

```js
    var svg = d3.select('svg').attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);

    var dataSet = [20, 20];

    var group=svg.append("g");
    var circles = group.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr("r",function(d){ return d })
    .attr("cx",function(d, i){ return i * 100 + 50 })
    .attr("cy",50)
    .attr("fill",'black');

    apply_transitions( group.select(":nth-child(1)"), ['a','b','c','d'] );

    apply_transitions( group.select(":nth-child(2)"), ['e','f','g','h'] );

  function apply_transitions( selection, tr_arr ) {

    var transitions = {
      a: function(){ return this.duration(1000).delay(1000).attr('cy', 200) },
      b: function(){ return this.duration(2000).delay(0).attr('r', 40) },
      c: function(){ return this.duration(500).delay(1500).attr('fill', 'red') },
      d: function(){ return this.duration(1500).delay(500).attr('opacity', 0.5) },
      e: function(){ return this.duration(1000).delay(3000).attr('cy', 300) },
      f: function(){ return this.duration(2000).delay(0).attr('r', 60) },
      g: function(){ return this.duration(500).delay(1500).attr('fill', 'magenta') },
      h: function(){ return this.duration(1500).delay(500).attr('opacity', 0.25) }
    };

      transitions[ tr_arr[0] ].call( selection.transition() )
        .on('end', function(){
          if ( tr_arr.length > 1 ) {
            apply_transitions( d3.select(this), tr_arr.slice(1) );
          }
        })
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Nice answer. However, the idiomatic way would be to use [`transition.call()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_call) instead of `Function.prototype.call()`. This allows for much cleaner method chaining. `transitions['a'].call( selection.transition() )` thus becomes something like `selection.transition().call(transitions['a'])`.

Comment: I completely forgot about `transition.call`! Thanks for the reminder.